# max iSCSI initiator session

Tags: windows, iscsi

what is iSCSI  initiator session limit   ?
and is there anyway to exceed this limit ?
i'm working on windows server
also in this documentation  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/iscsi/iscsi-target-server-limits ..... what's meant by  "Sessions that can simultaneously connect to an iSCSI target instance" .... is that the session that the target can host " or the initiator can start "
and what is the difference between forced and not forced

Answer (score 4):

## 256

it has never changed.

You have mixed up some questions. Each topic has a limit to answer and solve one issue.

Answer (score 3):

It's implementation specific (usually up to 256) and related to the target as well (target may reject # of the concurrent connections exceeding internal threshold value). Only to make things worse there's also a "multiple connections per session (MC/S)" thing which makes your question even more broad. Clarification question(s): What task are you trying to solve? Is it about increasing performance? Is it just a lab use case? What target are you trying to connect to?

Comment: i use mpio  so i can only connect to 128 disk ... i connect to a san solution which has no limitation

Comment: @BaronSamedi1958 he askes on Windows Server - and this limit has stand from today till Windows Server 2022 NOT changed and yes it might depend on other Platform - however it was specially asked for Windows Server :-)